# Elixir/Erlang: :ssl.start returns {:error, :already_listening} when starting on different IPs using {:reuseaddr, true}

Tags: erlang, elixir

I need to open two DTLS sockets on different IPs on the same port of the host.
Using **:gen_udp** with **{:reuseaddr, true}** it works fine.
But not with **:ssl.listen**

You can reproduce it with the following commands:

```
sudo ip addr add ::2 dev lo
```

And then in iex

```
:ssl.start

{:ok, socket} = :ssl.listen(20_100, [
  :binary,
  :inet6,
  {:active, true},
  {:reuseaddr, true},
  {:protocol, :dtls},
  {:ip, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
])

{:ok, socket2} = :ssl.listen(20_100, [
  :binary,
  :inet6,
  {:active, true},
  {:reuseaddr, true},
  {:protocol, :dtls},
  {:ip, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}}
])
```

The last :ssl.listen will not match with {:error, :already_listening}

How can i use **:ssl.listen** with the **:reuseaddr** option to start two DTLS sockets on different IP addresses on the same port of the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an Erlang Bug. The problem is solved in OTP 23.3.

https://github.com/erlang/otp/issues/4375

Answer (score -1):

Incase of IPV6, `::1/128` is the only address assigned to the loopback interface `lo` by default.

You need to assign `::2/128` also to the loopback interface. Then the second `:ssl:listen()` would work

Comment: This is what i did with: sudo ip addr add ::2 dev lo
The error message for an non existing IP is also different.

Comment: Try sudo ip -6 addr add ::2/128 dev lo

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, still the same problem. 
At least on my os (Ubuntu 18) the -6 option and specifying the prefix length with /128 is not required. 
sudo ip addr add ::2 dev lo and ip -6 addr add ::2/128 dev lo produce the same result when i look at my interfaces using ifconfig.

Comment: This is really weird, I am able to create two listen sockets using the same port but two different ip addresses {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1} and {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2} in erlang (`erl`) shell, but not in Elixir (`iex`) shell.